# Gateway URL is missing for DHL Carrier

Tags: magento2.4

Adobe documentation says there should be a gateway URL present inside DHL carrier however it's missing in our installation. Please help.

[image]

[image: r]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a documentation issue in magento 2.
The settings was there but from 2.3.4 may be that setting was remove.
You can check the settings into the following path in your directory.
vendor/magento/module-dhl/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

There is no such settings called Gateway Url. But same settings was found in the version of magento 2.2
Default API used in DHL :
https://xmlpi-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet

You can find the default settings for DHL in the vendor/magento/module-dhl/etc/config.xml

Comment: If that gateway URL is not there then how the shipping cost will be caculated? Which end point will it use to calculate the shipping cost?

Comment: Please check my edit asnwer